# How exactly does HAVING work with GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, having

As with most programmers, I want to be efficient in my code. In this case, I want everything in 1 statement rather than broken up into many parts.

I am writing a query that provides the highest carbon footprint of each industry group from the most recent year. I'm providing how many companies are in each industry group and grouped by the industry group and year, too.

I want to set MAX(year) in HAVING so that I have the most recent year, but is it possible to do so?

This is what I coded:

```
SELECT industry_group,
    COUNT(company) AS count_industry,
    ROUND(SUM(carbon_footprint_pcf), 1) AS total_industry_footprint
FROM product_emissions
GROUP BY industry_group, year
HAVING MAX(year) = year
ORDER BY total_industry_footprint DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This code provides the industry groups, the count of companies in each industry group, and the  carbon footprint of each industry group. HAVING MAX(year) = year doesn't do anything; I still get the highest carbon footprint in descending order, but it's not by the most recent year.

The correct code is:

```
SELECT industry_group,
    COUNT(company) AS count_industry,
    ROUND(SUM(carbon_footprint_pcf), 1) AS total_industry_footprint
FROM product_emissions
GROUP BY industry_group, year
HAVING year = 2017
ORDER BY total_industry_footprint DESC;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your "correct" code doesn't work if the most recent year is something else than 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has nothing to do with grouping. You need to filter the year.

```
SELECT industry_group,
    COUNT(company) AS count_industry,
    ROUND(SUM(carbon_footprint_pcf), 1) AS total_industry_footprint
FROM product_emissions
WHERE YEAR = (SELECT MAX(YEAR) FROM product_emissions)
GROUP BY industry_group
ORDER BY total_industry_footprint DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

If you need to filter based on industry groups then

```
SELECT industry_group,
    COUNT(company) AS count_industry,
    ROUND(SUM(carbon_footprint_pcf), 1) AS total_industry_footprint
FROM product_emissions pe
WHERE YEAR = (SELECT MAX(YEAR) FROM product_emissions pei where pe.industry_group = pei.industry_group )
GROUP BY industry_group
ORDER BY total_industry_footprint DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: This is a great answer. The first code block worked; I'm not entirely certain what you meany by pei in the second code block. What I am struggling to understand is when to use WHERE and when to use HAVING. The course told me to use WHERE when GROUP BY isn't involved; HAVING when GROUP BY is. So why exactly should I use WHERE and not include year in GROUP BY?

Comment: HAVING is to filter grouped content. like GROUP BY industry_group HAVING count(company) > 2. year does not need to be grouped in this case. we are not interested in past years but the most recent year.

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you please consider to accept it as an answer so that community can benefit from it.

Comment: This answer is very helpful and is actually why I was so confused. Essentially, I should use WHERE when I want to filter an exact year. For example, I would use WHERE year = (SELECT MAX(YEAR) FROM product_emissions) when filtering on one given year; HAVING MAX(year) < 2017 when filtering on grouped data related to year? Is that right?

Comment: In the second case, the maximum year in a group must be less than 2017 in order to match